# pinch zoom android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Pessoal o meu problema é o segunte. Estou precisando ampliar uma `ImageView` com aquele movimento de pinça bastante conhecido, mas já estou no terceiro dia pesquisando na internet como fazer e batendo a cabeça, mas o máximo que consegui foi um código de um tutorial que apenas amplia a imagem não permitindo a movimentação da imagem ampliada ela só amplia em um ponto fixo e fica. Estarei colocando o código e gostaria de saber como implementar a movimentação da imagem ou se alguem puder ajudar, colocar um código certo, pois como eu já afirmei bati a cabeça demais e não saiu nada aqui rsrs. Abraços.

```
public class tela87 extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private ImageView img;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private float scale = 1f;
    private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tela835gavetti);
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        SGD.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
            SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar o [`TouchImageView`](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView), ela suporta pinch zoom, double tap e outras funcionalidades.

Para implementa-la, basta referência-la em seu layout:

```
<br.com.seupacote.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/touch_img_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tentou editar a imagem do xml que é mais fácil? Pode alterar os valores de wrap_content para um valor em pixel. Exemplo: ''500.0 px''

```
<ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/img"     
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
  android:maxWidth="42dp"  
  android:maxHeight="42dp"  
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
  android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"  
  android:src="@drawable/minhaimagem"  
  />
```

Para ampliar dentro da aplicação a imagem tente assim:

```
SGD.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
SGD.setSupportZoom(true);
```